# Docker with tcp:// and --tls in WebStorm IDE

Tags: webstorm

I'd like to use the WebStorm IDE (Windows) to manage my Docker images. For the local installation it works perfectly fine, but I have problems with my secured instance.

I can connect with the following command:

```
docker -H tcp://<<URL>>:<<PORT>> --tls --tlskey <<path_to_key>>/key.pem --tlscert <<path_to_cert>>/cert.pem info
```

so I guess I just need the option to enable tls.

Does WebStorm or IntelliJ have this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option in PhpStorm 2017.3 EAP #PS-173.3415.21 (which should be pretty much the same), and also the docs for 2017.2 state, that you need to either use Unix socket or tpc without tls (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/docker.html#docker_settings).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019.1 (maybe earlier), it is possible (but appearently undocumented) to connect to a TLS-enabled docker daemon. Simply use `https://<host>:2376` instead of `tcp://<host>:2376` and make sure you either set the certificate directory or have your certificates in `~/docker/`. The files must be named `ca.pem`, `cert.pem` and `key.pem`.

Update: As I also just found out, in 2019.1 remote docker interpreters only work with Dockerfiles, not with docker-compose.